# how to get the correspond image_id and label when using predict_generator and flow_from_directory

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, image-preprocessing

I am using keras.preprocess.image.ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory to generate image batches. However, when I try to use model.predict_generator to predict the labels, I do not know the label and the correspond image_id. Anyone help me? My code is as follows:

```python
from keras.preprocess.image import ImageDataGenerator

from keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19
base_model = VGG19(...)
data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(...)

result = model.predict_generator(date_gen.flow_from_directory(valid_path), shuffle=False, target_size=(input_size, input_size))
```

I can get the result label, but how to get the correspond iamge_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following

```python
data_gen.filenames
```

Comment: That would only work if the generator was yielding the images in the same order as data_gen.filenames.